# The future of Erlang and BEAM

Tags: java, erlang, beam

Some time ago I got seriously interested in Erlang (coming from C++/PHP/Java world) - and I've seen it has been successfuly used in the industry, by `Ericsson`, `Facebook`, `Goldman Sachs`, etc. So, I thought it would be a great platform to build high demanding apps, with low-latency profile, with a lot cleaner and nicer language than, for example, Java (for me).

But after "wow effect" has gone, I discovered that there are many [high performance Java libraries](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/02/high-performance-libraries-in-java.html) that seem to resolve many problems that Erlang is theoretically best suited for (real-time, low-latency applications, concurrency, fault-tolerance, etc.). Moreover, it seems that there are things that, despite Erlang profile, are just not possible to achieve on BEAM (like [LMAX Disruptor concurrent framework](http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/)).

So the question arises: is Erlang still the best platform to build such `demanding applications` ? Wouldn't it be better if we stick to one, very mature (J)VM and try to make it even better than trying to achieve something similar with less resources available (size of OTP team vs. JVM team, supporters, etc) ? And is it possible at all to achieve this kind of `performance and adoption` with BEAM ?

And just to make things clear: I don't want to init a flame war here. I am just curious because I **really like Erlang** and I think it's a *great* platform and I'd like to invest time and effort to build real-life projects on it. But I'd just like to know what others might say about that and - if I am wrong - maybe someone could correct me.

Comment: I would copy-paste this into a discussion forum. Although it is too broad to be answerable (and thus not for a QA-site) it is exellent stuff for discussion.

Comment: I'll try to put it on Erlang mailing list but I just wanted to hear from a broader gremium, thus I asked here.

Comment: To answer the question: "is Erlang still the best platform to build such demanding applications ?" ... Yes it is.

Comment: Well, somewhat laconic answer but thank you anyway :)